# Use in parameter as table name in stored procedure inner sql definition

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, cursor, db2

Since a few changes were made during the answers here is the working procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SQLTEST(in intab VARCHAR(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE SQLCMD VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE tabname VARCHAR(50);
SET tabname=intab;

FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, CMD from COMMANDTBL
DO 
  SET SQLCMD = REPLACE(v.CMD, 'TABREPL', tabname); 

PREPARE myStmt FROM SQLCMD; 
EXECUTE myStmt;
END FOR;
END@
```

As shown I want to call the procedure with an in parameter that is to be the table name in the inner sql definition.

Calling it is:

```
CALL SQLTEST('targettbl')@
```

Thank you.

TheVagabond

Comment: Without the replace of the strings it is working fine, I just need to find a way to replace those strings inside the variable.

Comment: Sorry, misread a bit.  Note that you still have to validate the table name or face danger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does doing the logic in a single expression work?

```
SET SQLCMD = REPLACE(v.CMD, 'TABREPL', tabname);
```